# How much of a star falls into a black hole?

Tags: black-holes

http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/04/05/astronomers-may-have-witnessed-a-star-torn-apart-by-a-black-hole/

A lot of the star in the disc, a lot of the star in the jets, precisely how much of the star actually falls into the black hole?

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer for all cases.  Of course the upper-bound is 100% but in practice, even if nearly all of the matter would fall in, a huge amount of energy  will be radiated as x-rays and $\gamma$-rays due to heating in the accretion disk.

The dynamics of in-falling matter are quite complicated and very sensitive to initial conditions.  Currently super computers are required to answer this question in any detail for a given set of initial conditions.