# What would happen if an asteroid-sized primordial black hole encountered a very large star?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, estimation

What would happen if an asteroid-sized primordial black hole encountered a very large star? I thought about this and Googled for answers but got no results. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. I know by my own admission you can find errors in thinking by the question asked.

Comment: See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/648959/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8294/44126

Comment: Asteroids range in size from 10 km across to 100s of km across. If the entire mass of our sun collapsed to a black hole, it would be *less* than 10 km across. A black hole with the size of a large asteroid would have the same mass as a star much larger than our sun. Is this the situation you had in mind?

Comment: Sort of but I was thinking more the smallest stable blackhole say one with a few billion years left before evaporation and a super massive star magnitude larger than our yellow dwarf

Comment: What do you mean by "asteroid-sized"?

Comment: At which speed? Small, and they will form a binary object that eventually merges into one larger black hole. Large, and it will simply pass through, shaking things up a bit on the way.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/335942/what-happens-when-a-very-large-star-swallows-a-small-black-hole?rq=1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506845/what-would-happen-if-a-primordial-black-hole-with-5-10x-time-the-mass-of-earth?rq=1 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190308/throwing-a-micro-black-hole-into-the-sun-does-it-collapse-into-a-black-hole-or?rq=1

Comment: @profrob My impression was that black holes can be microscopic, so much so that they evaporate in microseconds. I mentioned primordial black holes because of their formation could vary from post expansion blackhole.
 Maybe not astroid sized. Maybe with a Schwarzschild radius of 5 meters. Who would win. The star or the baby  black holes?